# Why does PayPal use HTTP Request Headers for its API authentication?

Tags: http, http-headers, paypal, http-authentication

I'm just reading Paypal's API documentation, e.g. [Adaptive Accounts API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ACGettingStarted)

My question: What's the reason/advantage of using (custom?) HTTP Request Headers for authentication instead of "normal" POST/GET (or even COOKIE) variables?

In the mentioned example PayPal uses the following HTTP Request Headers:

```
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE
X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID
X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS
X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT
```

Comment: "normal" POST/GET is not the usual way to send your authentication.

Comment: ok, and what is the "usual way"? using custom headers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Why use HTTP headers rather than something in the body of the request?

By keeping your authentication info separate from the payload (the data you are transmitting) you make it easier to handle authentication at an earlier stage in the request pipeline. For example, a gatekeeper server can receive requests and authenticate them by looking only at the headers, and then pass them along to the module/server/class that does parses the request body and does the real work.

If the request fails authentication, it can be rejected before it even gets near the code that deals with the money.

Of course, you can architect your system this way no matter what, but keeping it in the headers means you don't need to parse the request body or even look at it. You also don't need to worry about adjusting `Content-Length:` if you wanted to modify the headers before passing it along to another server.

#### Why use custom HTTP headers rather than WWW-Authenticate or Cookie?

I think this is simply because PayPal wants a more robust scheme than either of these can accommodate. WWW-Authenticate only allows for basic (cleartext) and digest (MD5) authentication, and many better schemes have been developed since the spec for these was written. They also don't allow for more than a username and password.

Cookies are technically opaque bits of data that you receive from a server and pass back to it unchanged. Again, they could tell you how to generate the info that you pass along in a Cookie header, but that wouldn't really be following the spec, so at that point, why not just use some custom headers?

Comment: Excellent Explanation. @Mike, I'm no network expert but, afaik, API calls to PayPal are done via TCP/HTTP(which is built on top of TCP), and then you upgrade to TLS/SSL. These are all protocols which are widely used and have been for some time. You should download wireshark and watch the packets being sent back and forth. You can see the entire process.

Answer (score 2):

If the connection is trusted between two parties and SSL is implemented, `HTTP Authentication` is a **simple to implement** way to authenticate between two fixed parties. The connection is simply rejected at the traffic level if the authentication fails.

I don't think Paypal uses HTTP Authentication for payments? It's just for you to access API features to build your own admin interface for Paypal accounts?

Answer (score 2):

The **HTTP access authentication process** is described in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication", look [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

User agents are advised to take special care in parsing the WWW-Authenticate field value as it might contain more than one challenge, or if more than one WWW-Authenticate header field is provided, the contents of a challenge itself can contain a comma-separated list of authentication parameters.

Comment: Read the question. PayPal is using custom headers, not WWW-Authenticate.